# SQL Server : multiple rows with same column values except one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data like these:

```
name_text   ----------c_num---d_type-----unique_id----------------------v_text--r_ticket_id
29311875_FAD_V100.doc 3560709 Contract 21DABDDF49BA41289F1905D1D6B79ABF 2,01    28600206
29311875_FAD_V100.doc 3560709 Contract 21DABDDF49BA41289F1905D1D6B79ABF 2,01    28600240
Copy.docx             3560715 Guide    9D06F8EFF4EC4A2D862F5A0DB3BA357B 2       28600219
```

I want to select just one row which has the bigger value of `r_ticket_id` column, if `name_text`, `c_num`, `d_type`, `unique_id`, `v_text` columns values are equal.

In these case, with select statement just this columns should be fetched.

```
name_text   ----------c_num---d_type-----unique_id----------------------v_text--r_ticket_id
29311875_FAD_V100.doc 3560709 Contract 21DABDDF49BA41289F1905D1D6B79ABF 2,01    28600240
Copy.docx             3560715 Guide    9D06F8EFF4EC4A2D862F5A0DB3BA357B 2       28600219
```

What is the exact SQL query that will do this job?

Comment: are there any possibilities that a record may have same unique id but have different values on every column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be helpful when a record may have the same unique id but have different values on every column. Make use of `ROW_NUMBER` and window function. I guess they are already present on sql-server 2005.

```
SELECT name_text,c_num,d_type,unique_id,v_text,r_ticket_id
FROM
    (
        SELECT  name_text, c_num, d_type, unique_id, v_text, r_ticket_id,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY unique_id 
                                   ORDER BY r_ticket_id DESC) rn
        FROM tableName
    ) x
WHERE x.rn = 1
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3108f/1)

Comment: Thank you for this reasonable and instructive answer.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, we have `GROUP BY` operation to allow us to consolidate repeated rows. In your question, you want to roll up all the same values except for the `r_ticket_id.` For that one, you wish to find the biggest value which in SQL translates to the `MAX` function.

```
SELECT
    name_text
,   c_num
,   d_type
,   unique_id
,   v_text
,   MAX(r_ticket_id) AS max_r_ticket_id
FROM
    dbo.MyTableNameHere
GROUP BY
    name_text
,   c_num
,   d_type
,   unique_id
,   v_text
```